# Getting problem with width when i add Component In react

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, components, react-component

I Iam created WebPage in react with width 100% and when i add more component t to the web page te width of the horizontal Line screen is increased.. Need Solution

[problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHkLr.png)

For Example Code:-

```
    <div className="w-100">
 <COmponent1 />
<COmponent2 />
</div>
```

Comment: You can check if the components have margins.

Comment: can I get more code, or maybe it's because of global CSS, have you tried w-80 or something?

Answer (score 0):

This is more related to CSS instead of ReactJS, try to give some styles to all the blocks on the page, like

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

you can read more about box-sizing  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: All tried that One Not working

Comment: can you provide more information (code) in order for us to be able to help?